# Highlight subtitle's playing line- iOS

Tags: ios, highlight, subtitle

I'm trying to make an Karaoke app and I want to show at least three lines of lyrics and highlight the line which is playing. Now I'm adding an .srt file as subtitle. I want to know how I can show the subtitle in a textview and detect the playing line and highlight it?
Subtitle example:

00:00:01,242 —> 00:00:02,550
line one of lyrics

2
00:00:02,551 —> 00:00:04,104
line two of lyrics

25
00:02:05,458 —> 00:02:07,158
line three of lyrics

or if I need to add any other type of text for my subtitle?
I was searching and found a solution that I can use .kar file but I couldn't find any example or explanation of it's instruction. 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The time in player and time in subtitle file  .srt file will match, find the text string and highlight the specific string

Comment: @Vignesh I want to know how to find the text?

Comment: 1. You have the time in player
2. find the same time in .srt file
3. you will know the line of the lyric
4. find the range and highlight only that range in textview

Comment: this require a timer to check the file every second. I want to make use of any file format like .kar to make efficiency

Comment: please visit this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270964/highlighted-text-in-ios-karaoke-like-app?rq=1